# TypeError: {1, 3} is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, serialization, set

I'm a begginer in Python and I have a little problem with JSON. In the tutorial I'm working with there are two functions:

```
def read_json(filename):
    data = []
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        with open(filename, "r") as f:
            data = json.load(f)
    return data


def save_json(filename, data):
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        json.dump(data, f)
```

But when I try to save my data there's an error in saving:

```
raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: {1, 3} is not JSON serializable
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Can you post sample json data which you are writing and also check the type(data) which you are writing to file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{1, 3}` is a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset), which as the error points out, cannot be serialized to JSON - the only collection [types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example) in JSON are lists (called arrays in JSON) and dictionaries (called objects in JSON).

You'll need to convert it to a list:

```
converted = list(my_data)
save_json(my_filename, converted)
```

Comment: Glad to hear it. If you like, you can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) an answer that solves your problem by clicking the checkmark next to it ... this lets other people know that the solution worked.

Comment: sure. i'll do it.